# Error with discord bot 1.7.3 giving very long error

Tags: discord, discord.py, openai-api

I was trying to make a discord chat bot but I got this error I am not sure what to do by the way I am using discord 1.7.3 here is the code by the way the DISCORD KEY and OPENAI-KEY are not the problem those are to hide my openai key and discord bot key:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import openai
import os

openai.api_key = os.environ.get('OPENAI-KEY')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    elif message.content.startswith('$chat'):
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="davinci",
            prompt=message.content[5:],
            max_tokens=100,
            temperature=0.9,
            top_p=1,
            n=1,
            stream=False,
            logprobs=None,
            stop=["\n"],
        )
        await message.channel.send(response['choices'][0]['text'])

client.run(os.environ.get('DISCORD-TOKEN'))
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import openai
import os

openai.api_key = os.environ.get('OPENAI-KEY')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    elif message.content.startswith('$chat'):
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="davinci",
            prompt=message.content[5:],
            max_tokens=100,
            temperature=0.9,
            top_p=1,
            n=1,
            stream=False,
            logprobs=None,
            stop=["\n"],
        )
        await message.channel.send(response['choices'][0]['text'])

client.run(os.environ.get('DISCORD-TOKEN'))
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Private\OneDrive\Desktop\Pro\GitHub Repo\Discord_chat_bot\Bot.py", line 35, in <module>
    client.run(os.environ.get('DISCORD-TOKEN'))
  File "C:\Users\Private\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run   
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Private\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Private\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Private\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I was expecting for it to work if I try this code in 2.0.0 discord it give a different error

The reason I am using 1.7.3 not 2.0.0 is because I had a different error and to fix it I had to switch to 1.7.3

Comment: You also do need 2.x for you bot to work. otherwise you‘re not able to get the message content

Answer (score 1):

Error on this line:

```py
client.run(os.environ.get('DISCORD-TOKEN'))
```

The token you are passing in is None because `os.environ.get('DISCORD-TOKEN')` returns None.

You could have forgot to set your environment variable or you had it in a `.env` file. If you have it in a `.env` file, please load it:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
```